# require() not working in express script with Node

Tags: node.js, express, es6-modules

I've been following along with a [PERN stack tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7UQBMb8ZpuE&t=1815s&ab_channel=TheStoicProgrammers) from YouTube and I've started running into problems with using the require function in the index file for my server application running Node v 17.7.2 with Express 4.17.

The code that's throwing the errors is here:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");
const routes = require("./routes/jwtAuth")

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());
app.use('/auth', myRoutes);
app.get('/', (req, res) =>{
res.send('hello world!');
});
app.listen(process.env.PORT, ()=>
console.log('listening at port 3000'),
);
```

The error I get is:

```
const express = require("express");
                ^
ReferenceError: require is not defined in ES module scope, you can use import instead
This file is being treated as an ES module because it has a '.js' file extension and '/Users/Nizz0k/Sites/pgpengapi/package.json' contains "type": "module". To treat it as a CommonJS script, rename it to use the '.cjs' file extension.
```

From what I've read this error used to be limited to using `require()` in frontend code, but after Node v14 can happen in server scripts as well. I have the type set to `module`. The error seems to be relatively recent, as I've not had any crashing changes when using `require` in the app up to now.

Comment: If you have the `"type"` set to `"module"`, as the error confirms, then you indeed can't use `require`. Do you actually _want_ to use ES modules for your server code? If so, note ES modules use `import`. Also note it's not _syntactically_ invalid, it's just a function call, but a runtime error because that function doesn't exist in a module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use ES modules (ie. when you set type to `module`), you need to use the `import` syntax:

```
import express from 'express';
```

Comment: down a refactoring rabbit hole, but this worked.